# Running external C++ exe under Release Mode in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, exe

I have a third party C++ exe file that Im calling from my C# windows forms app:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "virtual.exe";
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = outfile + ".vxml";
proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Application.StartupPath;

proc.Start();
proc.WaitForExit();
```

It works perfect if my C# windows app is in "**Debug Mode**". If I then change to "**Release Mode**" it **crahses**.

Any clue why is that happening, and a way to solve it?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Why does it crash? How do you know it's crashing.. an exception dialog perhaps?

Comment: Are both your release and debug builds targeting the same architecture (32 or 64-bit)?

Comment: Yes both configurations target the same ANY CPU

Comment: If the C++ app is crashing it makes no sense to post the C# code that launches it. use a debugger to locate the general location of the crash and start looking there.

Comment: @VAAA can the c++ app launch outside of the C# app? Did you try running the c# program as admin?

Comment: @VAAA, we can't help much unless you tell us exactly what error you get and where/when you get it. "it crashes" is simply too vague.

Answer (score 0):

From what little information you provided I can guess, that the `virtual.exe` file simply does not exist in application's directory. If you use default settings, binaries are compiled to `bin\Debug` and `bin\Release` directories, respectively. Make sure, that `virtual.exe` is reachable from within the `bin\Release` (or wherever the release binary is copied to) directory.

If it is not the case, you have to provide more information, eg. how the program crashes, which line is faulty etc.